# Как сделать видимой первую ячейку?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, scrollview

У меня есть код, который обнаруживает последнюю ячейку, но мне любопытно, как теперь определить самую первую ячейку в tableView, потому что в моем tableView не все ячейки видны на устройстве, таком как iphone 7 или меньше, поэтому я должен использовать метод  scroll.

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

let contentOffsetMaxY: Float = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height)
let contentHeight: Float = Float(scrollView.contentSize.height)
let lastCellIsVisible = contentOffsetMaxY > contentHeight


if lastCellIsVisible {
 //some action
}
```

}

Comment: См. tableView.visibleCells и tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

Answer (score 0):

Бери количество ячеек из count массива который прилетел и определяй